# Modulus calculation in Javascript, need to write a code that can handle large powers using modulus rules

Tags: javascript, encryption, rsa, modulus

im currently working on a project about modulus calculation and RSA encryption.
My problem is that i need to use a modulus rule to get to the correct answer.
The rule that im trying to use is this(where my exponent is 25 and it need to be changeable): [image: picture of the rule]
I've tried this code (couldt get the code formatting to work):

```
function modpow(m,e,n){
  var e parseInt(document.getElementById("number_e").value);
  var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("number_n").value);

  var temparray = [];
  temparray.push[m % n];

  var temp = Math.pow(temparray[i],2) % n;
  var resultat = 1;

  for (i=0; i<e-1; i++){
    temp = Math.pow(temparray[i],2) % n;
  }
  while (e>0){
    resultat = resultat*temparray[i];
  }
}
```

And the thing is, i have some number, that needs to be in the power of my e and then mod n. I've thought of using some logarithmic calcutation rules to check how many times i need to power the 2, to get my number e.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] to illustrate your problem? The code you provided above has a syntax error in the second line, and even if you corrected that, it would still immediately clobber two of the function's three parameters before performing any calculations.

Comment: That rule is simply [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), see also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Pseudocode).